# How to remove QObject from parent

Tags: qt, qobject

How can I break parent-child ownership for a QObject? It seems that there is no longer an explicit way of doing this. Is it enough to call

```
QObject::setParent(NULL)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're correct. To make a `QObject` an orphan, simply do

```
// on C++11 compiler
object->setParent(nullptr); 

// on a pre-C++11 compiler
object->setParent(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Qt5 Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)

> You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents.